# Insertar a MySQL variable de sesion con validación de formulario PHP

Tags: php, mysql, php7, session

Tengo un archivo con el cual se valida un inicio de sesión que, el caso de ser exitoso, redirige al usuario a un formulario de html.

Este es el archivo de inicio de sesión:

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/login.php';
include_once 'includes/session.php';
$userSession = new UserSession();
$user = new User();

 if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
 //echo "hay sessión";
 $user->setUser($userSession->getCurrentUser());
 include_once "formulario.php";
 }else if(isset($_POST['usuario']) && isset ($_POST['password'])){
 //echo "Validación de Login";

 $userForm = $_POST['usuario'];
 $passForm = $_POST['password'];

if($user->userExists($userForm, $passForm)){
    //echo "usuario validado";
    $userSession->setCurrentUser($userForm);
    $user->setUser($userForm);
    include_once "formulario_reportes.php";
}else{
    //echo "algun dato incorrecto";
    $errorLogin = "Nombre de usuario y/o password es incorrecto";
    include_once "home.php";
}
}else{
//echo "home.php";
include_once "home.php";
}
?>
```

En caso de iniciar sesión exitosamente, el **formulario.php** se muestra en pantalla dando la bienvenida al usuario con el nombre correspondiente al inicio de sesión:

```
<html>
 <body>
   <h1> Bievenido <?php echo $user->getNombre(); ?> Contesta el formulario</h1>
   <form action="insertar.php">
     <input type="text" name="nombre">
     <input type="text" name="apellidos">
     <input type="number" name="edad">
     <button type="submit">Registrar</button>
   <form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Los datos escritos en el formulario son enviados por metodo  `POST`  al siguiente archivo donde son insertados a MySQL:

```
<?php
 include_once ('login_validate.php');
 include ("conn.php");
 $nombre= $_POST['nombre'];
 $apellidos= $_POST['apellidos'];
 $edad= $_POST['edad'];

 $insertar = "INSERT INTO reportes (usuario_logueado, nombre, apellidos, edad) VALUES ('$user->getNombre();', '$nombre', '$apellidos', '$edad')";

$resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $insertar);
if($resultado){
echo"<script>alert('Reporte registrado');
window.location.href='home.php'";
}else{
echo"<script>alert('ERROR');
window.history.go(-1)</script>";
}
?>
```

**LO ANTERIOR CLARAMENTE NO FUNCIONA, NECESITO INSERTAR EN LA CONSULTA MYSQL LA VARIABLE DEL USUARIO QUE HA INICIADO SESIÓN Y QUE ESTA CONTESTANDO SU FORMULARIO, PERO NO LOGRO ENVIAR LA VARIABLE YA QUE EN LA PÁGINA ES RECONOCIDA COMO *un objeto no valido*.**

Comment: De dónde sale la variable `$username` no la veo declarada por ningún lugar

Comment: Pregunto lo mismo que @Xerif. Además, tu tabla `reportes` peca de **redundancia de datos**. ¿Si se generan mil, diez mil o 5 millones de reportes, qué necesidad hay de repetir esas `N` veces el nombre, apellido, edad ... del usuario? Es mejor pasar el ID del usuario o en su defecto el username o la columna que identifique al usuario de manera única.

Comment: @Xerif coloqué esa variable como suposición a que existiera, mi pregunta es cómo la recupero en ese archivo?

Comment: @A.Cedano  coloqué esa variable como suposición a que existiera, mi pregunta es cómo la recupero en ese archivo. Necesito Guardar esa variable cada que se conteste el formulario ya que es un indicador de (¿Quién contesto el formulario?)

Comment: Eso se entiende perfectamente, pero debes sacar ese dato de alguna parte: de un formulario, de la variable de sesión, etc. Nosotros no podemos decirte de donde porque no conocemos el contexto, ni de qué modo llamas a ese archivo.

Comment: @A.Cedano  En el formulario de bienvenida utilizo ```<?php echo $user->getNombre(); ?>``` para identificar el inicio de sesión. Cómo puedo llevar ```$user``` para insertarlo en la estructura de la consulta.

Comment: Puedes guardarlo en la variable de sesión por ejemplo, y sacarlo de allí cuando lo necesites para hacer la inserción.

Answer (score 0):

lo que yo hago es usar variables de SESSION y a ellas le asigno un valor, y luego las llamo donde las necesito, de esta forma:

Primero verifico si el usuario es el correcto y luego inicio sesión y declaro la variable de SESSION y allí le asigno el valor que quiera algo así:

```
 $userForm = $_POST['usuario'];
 $passForm = $_POST['password'];
 if($userForm== "aqui el usuario" && $passForm == "aqui password"){
    //inicio sesión
    session_start();
    //asigno el valor que quiera a la variable de sesión
    $_SESSION["user"] = $userForm;
    //luego redirecciono a donde quiero que me lleve.
  }
```

Y por último en los archivos que las necesito las llamo de esta forma:

```
  //Mantenemos inicio de sesión
  session_start();
  //Muestro la variable
  echo $_SESSION["user"];
```